# Google Play and Cordova 4.1.1

Tags: android, cordova

Google Play is rejecting my application because of the Cordova version I use :

```
Apache Cordova
The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.

You can find information about how to upgrade in this Google Help Center article.
```

I updated to Cordova 4.1.1 and I still get this error when uploading a new build.

```
$ cordova -v
6.4.0

$ cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 4.1.1
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pretty simple : Google Play refused a build I sent in production with Cordova 3.5.0. Since this moment, for every `Alpha` build I sent, Google Play was complaining about my production build that was using Cordova 3.5.0. The only way to resolve this issue was to send a build in `Alpha`, and move it to `Production`, without being able to test it in `Alpha` mode through the Google Play. It's sad that we can't test any build in the Google Play Store in `Alpha` or `Beta` when there's a build with security issue in `Production`.

Hope this will help some people having this weird issue.